# How should I remove a link with a particular format?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to filter out the links which I dont't want. For example like this -

[image]

```
 if (query['fq'].includes('png') || query['fq'].includes('jpg')) {
          this.resultDisplay = 'images';
          this.searchdata.fq = 'url_file_ext_s:(png+OR+jpeg+OR+jpg+OR+gif)';
        } else if (query['fq'].includes('avi')) {
          this.resultDisplay = 'videos';
        } else {
          this.resultDisplay = 'all';
```

There are files loading which has `jpg` extension. How should I filter them out ? My project tech-stack is Angular 2. It would be great if someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you always have extension you can simply ignore the files which end with `jpg` and `jpeg` if any come through.

Comment: You could also use CSS, if you're needs are static. Using `a[href$='.jpg'] {display: none}`. I can make this an answer, if interested

Comment: @GillesC I have updated my question with code which is not working. Kindly look. Thanks.

Comment: @AP. Your solution is good. But it's not working bro! :)

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of strings:

```
var filtered=links.filter(link=>!link.includes(".jpg"));
```

Simply filter for not including .jpg...

Comment: Thanks man! I have updated my question with code which is not working. Can you help me with that ? It is very much similar to your code.